# Evaluating a struct inside of a conditional statement in C

Tags: c, if-statement, struct, conditional-statements

Is there a way to evaluate a struct variable inside of a conditional statement as a whole such that each element does not need to be written out? For example given the following struct:

```
typdef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} number;

number foo = {1, 2, 3};
```

I would like to evaluate the elements in an if statement such as:

```
if (foo.a == 1 && foo.b == 2 && foo.c == 3)
{
    ...
}
```

However, I want to evaluate the entire struct without having to list individual elements. I know this is not correct but this is along the lines of what I want to accomplish:

```
if (foo == {1, 2, 3})
{
    ...
}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can represent a temporary struct through a compound literal

```
(number) { 1, 2, 3 }
```

so a more logical attempt would look as

```
if (foo == (number) { 1, 2, 3 })
  ...
```

but it won't work, since C language does not provide a built-in operator for comparison of struct objects. You can use `memcmp` instead

```
if (memcmp(&foo, &(number) { 1, 2, 3 }, sizeof foo) == 0)
  ...
```

but unfortunately, this is not guaranteed to work due to unpredictability of the content of any padding bytes your struct objects might have in them.

The best course of action in this case might be to write a comparison function manually

```
inline bool is_same_number(const number *lhs, const number *rhs)
{
  return lhs->a == rhs->a && lhs->b == rhs->b && lhs->c == rhs->c;
}
```

and then use it in combination with compound literal feature

```
if (is_same_number(&foo, &(number) { 1, 2, 3 }))
  ...
```

Comment: Wow, now I believe you're reading my mind. However the padding, although implementation-defined, isn't going to change between instances of the same struct. Edit : scratch that, I misread.

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrey. The structure will be packed via "__attribute__((__packed__))." If so, how can I ensure that the compound literal would also follow a packed attribute for use in memcmp?

Comment: @quant: In all compilers I know the attribute applies to struct *type*, not to a specific object. That automatically ensures that *all* objects of that struct type are packed and packed identically, including the ones created through as compound literals.

Comment: @AndreyT Great information. That's very helpful. I would love to up vote your response, however I need a minimum of 15 reputations points. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Very good observation (and I almost mis-read the same way Quentin probably did). But -- since `int` is intended to have the "natural" size for a given machine it's for this special structure rather unlikely to have any padding. In order to be sure one could probably write an assertion testing `sizeof(number) == 3*sizeof(int)`. That would be really useful for structs with shorter elements in them to ensure they don't contain holes, e.g. because the compiler was instructed to pack them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you need a struct but either way just cast to unsigned char * and use a literal where 0x000000010002 would be the format of the literal representing 3 integers  {0 1 2}.

To avoid issues with endianess just declare the integral as a value at runtime and then the representation will match the system endian.

You could also use a macro if run time definition was not allowed.

I wouldn't waste the memcpy.

Comment: Always was and always will be until the concept is done away with :-D